# Output two time values in ascending order

Tags: c++, class, time

I'm having some issues outputting two objects of a class (t1 and t2) in ascending order after prompted user to input two time values. I know there is some mistake in the way the bool and if constructs are structured. Any help would be appreciated!

```
bool lessthan(Time t2) //For two Time objects t1 and t2, t1.lessthan(t2) returns true if t1 is less than, or comes before t2.
{
    if (hours < t2.hours)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (minutes < t2.minutes)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (seconds < t2.seconds)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


bool greaterthan(Time t2)  //For two Time objects t1 and t2, t1.greaterthan(t2) returns true if t1 is greater than, or comes after t2.
{
    if (hours > t2.hours)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (minutes > t2.minutes)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (seconds > t2.seconds)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


bool equalto(Time t2) //For two Time objects t1 and t2, t1.equalto(t2) returns true if t1 is equal to, or is the same time as t2.
{
    if (hours == t2.hours)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (minutes == t2.minutes)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (seconds == t2.seconds)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

In the main functions I have the following code:

```
 cout << "\nTime values entered in ascending order: "<<endl;
        if (t1.lessthan(t2))
            t1.write();
        cout << endl;
            t2.write();
        cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the equal-class should be

```
bool equalto(Time t2) //For two Time objects t1 and t2, t1.equalto(t2) returns true if t1 is equal to, or is the same time as t2.
{
    if (hours != t2.hours)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (minutes != t2.minutes)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (seconds != t2.seconds)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

In your code it would be enough if the hours are them same, independent of minutes and seconds. In mine version I reversed the logical order.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! However it still doesn't run properly. Also, if I type in two values that start with the same digit (e.g. 08:35:45 followed by 05:32:56) it only prints out the latter.

Comment: Did you show the complete output code in your question? Because `t1.write()` will only be called if t1 is smaller, `t2.write()` in any case.

Answer (score 0):

For your comparison functions, try:

```
bool equalto(Time t2) //For two Time objects t1 and t2, t1.equalto(t2) returns true if t1 is equal to, or is the same time as t2.
{
    if (hours == t2.hours && minutes == t2.minutes && seconds == t2.seconds)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool lessthan(Time t2) //For two Time objects t1 and t2, t1.lessthan(t2) returns true if t1 is less than, or comes before t2.
{
    if (hours > t2.hours)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (minutes > t2.minutes)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (seconds > t2.seconds)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then just implement greaterthan() in terms of the other two functions

```
greaterthan(Time t2)
{
    return (!(equalto(t2) || lessthan(t2));
}
```

Also, you're going to need to do something like this if you want to output the times in ascending order:

```
cout << "\nTime values entered in ascending order: "<<endl;
if (t1.lessthan(t2))
{
    t1.write();
    cout << endl;
    t2.write();
    cout << endl;
}
else
{
    t2.write();
    cout << endl;
    t1.write();
    cout << endl;
}
```

With your current code, the final 3 lines will always be executed, because they're unrelated to that if statement. You need parentheses.